# How do I keep an image in html to not move with the rest of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, image

Is it possible to keep an image from moving while the user scrolls through a web page. like the user always sees the image? I'd imagine it'd be possible using a  but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

Use the css `position: fixed;` attribute, specifying `top` and `left` absolute attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  background-image: url("http://yoursite.com/path/to/image.gif");
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```